# Shopify public app update new product/order/customer data

Tags: oauth, shopify

I have created a Shopify Public App using OAuth and I am accessing customer, order and product data. Everything is working fine. However, I wanted to know how do I access a newly created customer, order or product?

Are webhooks the only way I can keep my data in sync? If yes, can I add webhooks programmatically via my Public App?

Comment: yes, you can create webhooks via api.

Comment: Hello @miglio thanks for the reply. Yes I found the document which tells how to create webhooks via API. However, which scope/s do I need to ask the shop owner during OAuth app installation for different webhooks?